# Списки: cреднее арифметическое и сравнение элементов

Tags: python, список, сравнение

Дан одномерный список. Вводим вручную. Нужно найти номер элемента, который менее других отличающегося от среднего арифметического;
найти сумму элементов списка, расположенных между первым и вторым положительными элементами.

Попробовал вот так:

```
#ввод элементов массива 
print('Введите элементы массива')
my_list = [float(x)for x in input().split()]
my_select_min = []
my_select_max = []
#количество чисел 
print('Введите количество элементов в массиве')
n = int(input())
#вычислим среднее арифметическое и индекс числа
b = sum(my_list)
c = b/n
for a in my_list:
    if a <= c:
        my_select_min.append(a)
        max = max(my_select_min)
    if a >= c:
        my_select_max.append(a)
        min = min(my_select_max)
if c-min < max-c:
    print(my_list.index(min))
else: print(my_list.index(max))
```

Это первая часть кода (моя) и в нем ошибка line 24, in  min = min(my_select_max)

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Далее код уже не мой, гугланул. Вроде считает, но не могу понять, почему неверно.

```
#пробуем посчитать сумму между положительными элементами
s = 0
neg = -1
for n,i in enumerate(my_list):
    if n < 0:
        neg = i
        break
for n in my_list[neg+1:]:
    s += abs(n)
print(s)
```

Не пойму, что нужно еще добавить, чтобы корректно считало

Спасибо

Comment: "номер (не индекс) элемента"... если не индекс, то значение, если номер, то - индекс

Comment: вас не смущает, что вы создаете переменные min и max, совпадающие по названию со встроенными методами python? а потом их же вызываете как методы? нет? все нормально?

Comment: зачем сначала вводить элементы массива. а потом еще вводить из количество?

Comment: @strawdog понял, исправлю названия. Количество вводится для подсчета среднего арифметического. Что можете сказать по второй части кода?

Comment: Зачем вводить отдельно количество, если у вас есть все значения списка, вот в чем вопрос. Вы же можете посчитать длину списка самостоятельно? Я просто не могу понять ваш уровень понимания питона...

Answer (score 1):

Вы сильно усложняете решение задачи

```
# среднее арифметическое:
my_list = [float(x)for x in input().split()]
mean = sum(my_list)/len(my_list)
```

Допустим, ввели список:

```
my_list = [1.0, -1.5, 2.4, -1, -3]
```

тогда:

```
mean = sum(my_list)/len(my_list) # -0.42000000000000004
```

Далее, индекс ближайшего числа к среднему арифметическому:

```
closest = sorted(list(enumerate(my_list)), key=lambda x: abs(x[1]-mean))[0][0]
```

в нашем случае closest будет `3`. Действительно, число с индексом 3 ближе всего к среднему арифметическому

Теперь вычисляем сумму между первыми положительными числами списка (в данном случае, включая сами эти числа):

Для начала отбираем все положительные числа из списка и получаем их индексы:

```
positive = [x for x in enumerate(my_list) if x[1]>0][:2]
# positive будет [(0, 1.0), (2, 2.4)]
```

Затем берем индексы этих чисел и вычисляем сумму значений в срезе исходного списка:

```
positive_sum = sum(my_list[positive[0][0]:positive[1][0]+1])
```

получаем 1.9

Действительно, первые два положительных числа нашего списка - 1.0 и 2.4. Сумма между ними, включая сами числа : `1.0 + (-1.5) + 2.4 = 1.9`

Если нужно найти сумму элементов между первыми положительными значениями, не включая эти самые значения, то тогда делаем так:

```
positive_sum = sum(my_list[positive[0][0]+1:positive[1][0]])
```

Получаем -1.5

Итого, все ваши вычисления сводятся к 5 строкам кода.

Comment: Не стоит искать минимум через сортировку.